# Test Cases for moving files to folder A to folder B

Tags: testing

Write test cases to move all files from folder A to folder B (I don’t know the number of file present in folder A and B as well as I don’t know if there are file having same name in folder B).

Comment: Do you mean, write test cases to test this function?

Comment: Plz Be More clear on your query here.. writing test cases..?? Manual, automated, need script for ?? Platform.

Comment: @Ethel: Yes, test cases to test this function.

Answer (score 0):

When writing testcases, I find it best to brainstorm.

Sit down and think:
1. Positive: What are all the NORMAL ways I can do action X?
2. Positive: What are all the CRAZY/non-normal ways I can do action x?
3. Negative: What should generate error messages / not be allowed?
4. Positive/Negative: What actions can I do the developer didn't think of?
5. What stress tests can I apply?

Talk with the devs, other testers and your manager to see what you missed. Enjoy.